# Input form that will accept string of characters and redirect to URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a form on a page that requires the user to input text. Once the form is submitted by clicking a button it will run sanitizeDomainInput() and redirectLink(domain), the user will then be redirected to the URL in the function redirectLink(). Any advice?

[Form example is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEgkk.png)

```
function redirectLink(domain) {
  return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`
}


function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
input = input || 'unknown.com'
if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
input = input.substr(7)
}
if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
input = input.substr(8)
}
var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com'
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your question is.

Comment: God point. I need to create a input field that will take any string of character using the function provided above and on click run that function and re-direct to a URL

Comment: Okay, that's your plan. But what is your problem/question now? Is something not working?

Comment: Yes, Ive created a simple form but need to understand the steps to call the function

Comment: Okay. I think ethergeist's answer provide already the solution/demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your function could change the users location directly:

```
function redirectLink(domain) {
  window.location.href = `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`
}
```

Or with a more "redirecty" feel:

```
function redirectLink(domain) {
  window.location.replace = `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`
}
```

([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) on `window.location`)

Basic form

```js
function redirect() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["domain"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Domain must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert(`you entered ${x}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return redirect()">
    Domain: <input type="text" name="domain">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how do I create this in a form with a button. I'm very new to html/js. Where would I put the function in a simple one input form with a button. But also accepts and argument (domain) and the function sanitizeDomainInput(input)

Comment: Maybe start here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and try to work your way through. If you are without prior knowledge of these topics, it's kinda out of scope for a format like this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am very eager to learn foundations. Appreciate the resource link